# Как называется эта конструкция в javaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Например:

```
let testObject;
const value = testObject?.value.
```

(Я про "`?`" перед точкой.) Это оператор? C какой версии ноды появилась его поддержка?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

Поддержку см. [тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining#browser_compatibility) или [тут](https://node.green/#ES2020-features-optional-chaining-operator-----) (браузерную ещё [тут](https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining)).